# Angular + Firebase not binding three ways

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm just starting out with AngularFire and can't seem to get the three-way binding happening.

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.item = Item.find($stateParams.id);
```

and in the item service I have

```
.factory('Item', ['$firebase','FIREBASE_URL', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'items');

  var Item = {
    find: function(id) {
      return $firebase(ref.child(id)).$asObject();
    }
  };

  return Item;
}]);
```

I then have a `input` in my view that gets updated with the right item value from Firebase but when I type in textbox it doesn't update Firebase. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I have a solution but it would be nice to know whether this is the way to do it.
I have an `ng-change` in my textbox which calls a function in my Controller. The contoller then calls `$scope.item.$save($scope.item.text);`

Comment: Think I'm missing an extra `$bind` somewhere

Comment: To synchronize the object changes automatically back to Firebase, you have to call `$firebase(ref.child(id)).$asObject().$bindTo($scope, "data");`.

Comment: Is my solution the "wrong way" because it appears to work well?

Comment: Went with my approach in the end as even though I got the `$bindTo` approach working it was resetting the cursor position in the textbox to the beginning when I typed too fast!!!

Comment: Both approaches have their merits. When you explicitly trigger the `ng-change` event, you have more control over when the data gets saved. On the other hand: using `$bindTo` is more of a set-it-and-forget-it approach.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen has the gist of it here. Both are valid approaches. The jumping cursor was fixed in a recent release; you're probably a bit out of date.

Comment: I'm using 1.0.21 for Firebase and 0.8.2 for AngularFire - are these out of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To synchronize the object changes **automatically** back to Firebase, you have to call `$firebase(ref.child(id)).$asObject().$bindTo($scope, "data");`. That sets up the binding you are looking for.

Both approaches have their merits. When you explicitly trigger the `ng-chang`e event, you have more control over when the data gets saved. On the other hand: using `$bindTo` is more of a set-it-and-forget-it approach.